# AWS support API access denied

Tags: aws-sdk

I am trying to access trusted advisor programmatically. It give 403 access denied error.

I gave the AWSupportAccess policies to user

```sh
aws support describe-severity-levels
```

An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the DescribeSeverityLevels operation: User: arn:aws:iam::*****:user/UNA is not authorized to perform: support:

Comment: Check your creds and/or permissions to that resource

Answer (score 2):

The policy "**AWSupportAccess**" was missing. It worked after attaching the policy.